# hibernate. OneToOne mapping in database

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, mapping, one-to-one

I have following mapping:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="terminal_user")
public class TerminalUser {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<UserContent> userContentSet;
    ....
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_content")
public class UserContent {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    TerminalUser user;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "userContent")
    Content content;
    ...
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "content")
public class Content {
@OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_content_id")
    UserContent userContent;
    ....
}
```

After setting `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` to create

I see following database diagram:

[image]

For me relation of tables `user_content` and `content` is not one to one.

It looks same as relation of `terminal_user` and `user_content` and it is one to many

What do I wrong?

Comment: I know this does not answer your question, but why don't you just use the reverse engineering tools? It make life a lot easier! Get your database ready then "magic"!

Comment: For example sybase power designer?

Comment: simply hibernate tools to go from your database to code. And you can use MySQL workbench or whatever tool you want to use, to go from the diagram to the database. That's how I always do. I never write my own mapping. I simply add what hibernate does not generate automatically.

Answer (score 0):

A unique constraint will make the difference:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "content")
public class Content {
@OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_content_id", unique=true)
    UserContent userContent;
    ....
}
```